# How to get rEFInd working with FileVault 2 on OSX 10.8

Tags: linux, osx-mountain-lion, bootloader, efi

I installed rEFInd on my new Macbook Air which I planned on using to do a dual boot to Linux, but prior to installing Linux, I decided to encrypt my drive. I knew I was going to do this, so I had already installed rEFInd with the `--esp` option.

When I rebooted after this however, it seemed to have deselected rEFInd for boot. I reinstalled, but when I did and rebooted, my Mac partition would not show up in the bootloader (only the recovery partition). I ended up needing to hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Options</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to get it to boot again.

Any help getting these two to work together would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Reading through [this thread](http://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/5c7d0195/), I found some guidance for mac os 10.7 in [this](http://sourceforge.net/p/refind/discussion/general/thread/5c7d0195/#86ef/1141/6eea/c964/debf) comment, but later comments seem to indicate rEFIt should handle most of this automagically now (a year later).

Have you re-installed rEFIt after turning on the encryption?

I would suggest getting both OSes working with rEFIt and then turning on the disk encryption.

Answer (score 0):

what i did was backing up my computer setting it up as new and leaving the encryption off so i install refind and enjoyed it very much. installing some of ubnix based OS'es without any problem